# Get a detail after open popup

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap for popup

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

here there is two button is open same popup. I want to get which button is clicked. i want that button id

is it possible to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with bootstrap modal [event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) listener,

modal trigger buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id='2' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id='3' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

event script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
        alert(id);
     });
});
```

Working Example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
 var id = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');
 alert(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id='2'>Open Modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id='3'>Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id='2' ng-click="get_id_function(2)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id='3'
ng-click="get_id_function(3)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

In javasscript

```
$scope.get_id_function(id){}
```

thus you can receive id in the function parameter id